# Add an Icon using pure HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, icons

i would like to know if there's any way I could add a fas-fa clock icon using pure html. Reason being, I'm currently doing an assignment using a free wordpress account. Because its free, i have alot of limitations(no javascript, no CSS). only pure HTML coding.

```html
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<i class="fas fa-clock" style="color:grey;"></i>

</body>
```

Comment: Use an external source (img or svg) to load the icon

Comment: I haven't worked with wordpress for a while but i am sure i never had limitations on what to use . Especially not CSS and JS. You should be allowed to use that. Also....HTML is not coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/951a0d011f8c832991750c16136f8e260efa60b5/svgs/solid/lock.svg" alt="lock" height="20px" width="20px">
```

You can easily put them as an image as in this example.

you can find more svg icons of font-awesome on GitHub on this link https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/svgs

Comment: @Kinja please mark this answer as correct if it satisfies your requirement

Answer (score 1):

You could easily download the svg and host it as a raw svg on github or something of the likes and link to it as an image, it's dirty but it works

Answer (score 1):

An alternative you can use is uni characters [here](https://graphemica.com/search?q=clock)

```html
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<i class="fas fa-clock" style="color:grey;"></i>

<span>&#128339;</span> <!-- new---- -->



</body>
```